# creating a copy and paste program in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, but I wanted to create a specialized copy and paste program that could copy certain parts of text (from perhaps a notepad file) and paste them on a new file. Specifically, I want the program to begin copying when it recognizes certain key words, and stop copying at other key words. For example, suppose I start copying whenever I see the words "cat" or "dog," and stop copying when I see the words "ate" or "jumped." So suppose my text is: "The cat ate the dog. It also jumped onto the table." The output would be "cat dog. It also" Does anyone know how I can write such a program?

Comment: Have you tried anything till now ? 
Refer FileInputStream and FileOutputStream.

Comment: As you described, using Java, can't be done.  You simply don't have enough access to the OS and other windows within the system. Maybe with JNI/JNA

Comment: We'd like to see what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given any code of what you have tried. I can just provide you the solution of what can be done to solve your problem step by step.

```
  1> Read the file word-by-word.
  2> Then check for specific word you want to start the copy at. 
  3> When you find that specific word,
    start storing all the words in a string . 
  4> while copying also
    check for the word were you want to stop copying(you can do this by
    setting a flag which will be set once you find the start word and
    will be unset once you get the stop word.).  
  5> Later copy that string variable to clipboard.
```

I guess that's fulfills your requirement.
If you post your code, developers will be in better state to help you.